# symbol lookup error: symbol exists, I know where it is, how do I get my SO to "see it"?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, ld, symbols

I am writing a plugin module for a larger program, written in C++. I have never written a SO library before. My module compiles and links correctly (I think) however the main program loading the SO crashes with the error `symbol lookup error`.

The module I am writing worked fine, until I started to try and use other libraries within it. (Specifically caffe)

- There is a main program which is developed by another group
- I am writing a plugin module for this program
- My plugin module uses functions / code from [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org) (from the libcaffe.so file, Caffe itself is a compiled binary just to add to confusion)
- The main program crashes with the following error

`/path-to-binary/binary-name: symbol lookup error: ./build/libTestModule.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe2db5GetDBERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`

I tried adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib` to my `.bashrc`.

I did this because (after some internet searching - I don't actually understand what I am doing here) I ran

```
nm -g libcaffe.so | grep _ZN5caffe2db5GetDBERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

in the folder `/usr/lib` and that symbol exists in `libcaffe.so`.

```
00000000001cbb30 T _ZN5caffe2db5GetDBERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

- `libcaffe.so` is in `/usr/lib` and contains the symbol that my program cannot find.
- My understanding is that (for some reason which is not known to me) I have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/lib` so that my program can find `libcaffe.co` and the symbols contained within it.
- However I would have assumed that since `/usr/lib` contains loads of "default" `.so` files, that this would be searched regardsless of whether `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was set, ie shouldn't this directory be searched by default?
- Regardless of the above question, I don't know what I should try next.
- *How can I get my program to find the symbol above in `libcaffe.so`?*

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(TestModule)

find_package(Falaise REQUIRED)

add_library(TestModule SHARED TestModule.h TestModule.cpp)

set(Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/caffe")
set(Caffe_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/libcaffe.so")

target_link_libraries(TestModule PUBLIC Falaise::FalaiseModule)
```

Comment: Edit your post to show us the linkage command that generates your plugin `.so`

Comment: @MikeKinghan It's a CMake build - is the CMakeLists.txt file relevant?

Comment: Yes it should be sufficient to post the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @MikeKinghan Done

Answer (score 0):

Your `libTestModule.so` is, you say, dependent on `libcaffe.so` but you are
not linking it. This:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(TestModule)

find_package(Falaise REQUIRED)

add_library(TestModule SHARED TestModule.h TestModule.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TestModule PUBLIC Falaise::FalaiseModule caffe)
```

is how you would do so.